# What does "beamed in the head" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What does **"beamed"** mean in the following sentence? (**my guess is "hit"?**) Whether or not, is the usage of beam in this way common??

> Groot grunted a rude answer that stunned Rocket. But there were
>   weapons of torment and destruction to be seen and they needed to begin
>   their journey, so Rocket ushered Groot to the back. **He had to dodge
>   being beamed in the head by Thor’s backpack.**
>
> *THE AVENGERS 3*

The context is:

Rocket is a genetically modified raccoon; Thor, the thunder god; together with Groot, a tree-person, the three are about to be on trip to another planet.

Comment: Did you hear or read this? Seems like your question is based on an error: "beaned". I'm not sure "beamed" is a "legitimate" usage.

Comment: I quoted it from a book I am reading now. I am not sure it's a printing mistake, or a purposeful usage, as Rocket is a raccoon, much shorter than Thor, whose backpack  was as "beam" for rocket to hit onto? (English is my second language, I am so not sure, that why I asked if "beamed" is used in this way)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word could be **beaned.**

**Beaned** = "Hit in the head with a thrown object. Originally a baseball term, in that context it means "hit in the head with a pitch" ([Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=beaned)).

If the text actually says "**beamed** by a backpack" it could mean that the backpack emited some sort of rays or energy, but it does not mean being hit by a backpack itself.

**Beam** means to emit - usually some kind of rays ([Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/beam)). "In 1989 it was suggested that power could also be usefully **beamed by** laser from Earth to space" (Space-based solar power from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-based_solar_power)).

Answer (score 1):

American baseball players say "beaned" or "beanball;"
British cricket players say "beamed" or "beamer":
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beamer_(cricket)